# Index Action Java Spring Controller

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, spring-mvc, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I am coming from a Rails background and am delving into Java. I have been working on a boilerplate project that has a show action defined in the MatchesController.java;

```
@RestController
final class MatchesController {

private final MatchRepository matchRepository;

@Autowired
MatchesController(MatchRepository matchRepository) {
    this.matchRepository = matchRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/matches/{id}")
ResponseEntity<Match> show(@PathVariable String id) {
    Match match = matchRepository.findOne(id);

    if (match == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(match, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  }
}
```

In Rails, the show action would look something like this;

```
def show
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
end
```

The index action would look like;

```
def index
  @matches = Match.all
end
```

I am looking for how I would write an equivalent index action in Java/Spring and I feel like I'm supposed to define or use some sort of List or Array object in order to retrieve all of the matchRepository records:

I tries something like the following, but of course it is wrong and won't compile. The show action does work fine and interacts with my local mysql db just fine. I'm just a complete java/spring newbie and am toying around.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/matches")
ResponseEntity<Match> index() {
    Match matches = matchRepository.findAll();

    if (matches == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(matches, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Compilation errors;

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

/Users/home/Latta/Spring/pong_matcher_spring/src/main/java/org/pongmatcher/web/MatchesController.java:[36,48] incompatible types: java.util.List cannot be converted to org.pongmatcher.domain.Match
[INFO] 1 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `MatchRepository#findAll()` method has a return type of `List<Match>`. You can't assign such a value to a variable of type `Match`.

You'll need

```
List<Match> matches = matchRepository.findAll();
```

and then will need to change your return type to match

```
ResponseEntity<List<Match>> index() {
```

Java is strongly typed.

Additionally, if not already included, you must import the List package.

```
import java.util.List;
```